# How to check instance state use "aws-sdk" in ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have created an instance using `run_instances` method on EC2 client.
I want to check for whether instance is running or not.
One way to do is use `describe_instances` method and parse the response object.
I want to keep checking for instance state periodically till the instance state is `:running`.  Anybody knows how to do that?
Is there any simpler way rather than parsing the response object?
(I can't use `fog` gem since it does not allow me to create instances in a VPC)

Answer (score 4):

The v2 `aws-sdk` gem ships with waiters. These allow you to safely poll for a resource to enter a desired state. They have sensible limits and will stop waiting after a while raising a waiter failed error.  You can do this using the resource interface of the v2 SDK or using the client interface:

```
# resources
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new
ec2.instance(id).wait_until_running

# client
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new
ec2.wait_until(:instance_running, instance_ids:[id])
```

Comment: This seems much more cleaner will definitely try this

Answer (score 1):

`wait_until` methods are definitely better than checking statuses on yourself.

But just in case you want to see instance status:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'aws-sdk'

Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY'])
})

ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new

instance_id = 'i-xxxxxxxx'

puts ec2.describe_instance_status({instance_ids: [instance_id]}).instance_statuses[0].instance_state.name
```

Answer (score -1):

here is something to start with:

```
i = ec2.instances[instance_id]
i.status
while i.status != :running
 sleep 5
end
```

Comment: I am assuming `ec2` object in your code is the AWS client and in v2 `instances` property does not exist. Also for getting the latest status it has to make an API call in the background right? how does it work in your code?

Comment: I would caution against this approach as it can loop infinitely if the instance does not transition successfully into the running state. Also, this is for v1, not v2.

Comment: yeah I know, its a very limited solution, I also limited the amount of retries and did an exponential backoff for my production code. In any case, this is just something very simple to start from, as listed.